# Setting column equal to lagged value of another column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column where the date is recorded and I want to set another column to the lagged version of the date column. In other words, for every date I want the new column to have the previous date. 
I tried a lot of stuff, mostly stupid, and I got nowhere. My main issue was that I was updating a column based on where clauses from the same table and same column and MySQL doesn't allow it.

An example of the data follows below. My goal is to update colum PREVDATE, with the previous row from DATA_DATE with the condition that GVKEY is the same for both rows. I would define previous row as follows, order by GVKEY and DATE_DATE ASC and for every row (given that GVKEY is the same ) I want the previous one

```
+--------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
| DATA_DATE    |PREVDATE|  PRICE  | GVKEY | CUR_DEBT |  LT_DEBT    |
+--------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
| 1965-05-31   |   NULL | -17.625 | 1004  | 0.198    | 1.63        |
| 1970-05-31   |   NULL | -18.375 | 1004  | 2.298    | 1.58        |
+--------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: I guess you need a join update. MySQL won't allow you update the the same table in your sub query.

Comment: how many rows might have a given GVKEY? what defines "to have the previous date" from an ordering perspective

Comment: It may have thousands. I would define previous row as follows, order by GVKEY and DATE_DATE ASC and for every row I want the previous one

Comment: and DATA_DATE  is `Datetime` and not a home-spun type

Comment: @DrewPierce It's in DATE format.

Comment: and the min of Data_Date for a given GVKEY is never null in column `PREVDATE` ? and this is to fix data one time and not perpetuate poorly inserted data moving forward?

Comment: on another topic, this sounds like a financial application (note i said like). sounds like it is saving end-point sum or final state values. might be better normalized with transactions piling up in a GVKEY transaction table. Like debits and credits. You get to final state by joins. have a datetime not date. no need to care about PREVDATE. might be relevant to think about, might not. acct systems wouldn't do PREVDATE

Comment: price could be at the entity level with a pricing history table. that is it is not suited for up and down changes by differences (plus or minus) to get to price. However, debt columns are perfect for debit and credit entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach that makes use of MySQL user-defined variables, and behavior that is *not guaranteed*, but which see as consistent (at least in MySQL 5.1, 5.5 and 5.6).

WARNING: this returns *every* row in the table. You may want to consider doing this for a limited range of gvkey values, for testing. Add a WHERE clause...

```
         SELECT IF(r.gvkey=@prev_gvkey,@prev_ddate,NULL) AS prev_date
              , @prev_gvkey := r.gvkey                   AS gvkey
              , @prev_ddate := r.data_date               AS data_date
           FROM (SELECT @prev_ddate := NULL, @prev_gvkey := NULL) i
          CROSS
           JOIN mytable r
         ORDER BY r.gvkey, r.data_date
```

The order of the expressions in the SELECT list is important, we need to compare the value of the current row to the value "saved" from the previous row, before we save the current values in the @prev_ variables, for the next row.

We need a conditional test to make sure we're still working on the same gvkey. The first data_date for a gvkey isn't going to have a "previous" data_date, so we need to return a NULL.

For best performance, we'll want to have a covering index, with `gvkey` and `data_date` as the leading columns:

```
   ... ON mytable (gvkey,data_data)
```

The index can include additional columns, after those, but we need those two columns first, in that order. That will allow MySQL to return the rows "in order" using the index, and avoid an expensive "Using filesort" operation. (Extra column from EXPLAIN will show MySQL "Using index".)

---

Once we get that working correctly, we can use that as an inline view in an `UPDATE` statement.

For example:

```
UPDATE mytable t
  JOIN (
         SELECT IF(r.gvkey=@prev_gvkey,@prev_ddate,NULL) AS prev_date
             , @prev_gvkey := r.gvkey                    AS gvkey 
             , @prev_ddate := r.data_date                AS data_date
          FROM (SELECT @prev_ddate := NULL, @prev_gvkey := NULL) i 
         CROSS
          JOIN mytable r
         ORDER BY r.gvkey, r.data_date
       ) s
    ON t.gvkey     = s.gvkey
   AND t.data_date = s.data_date
   SET t.prev_date = s.prev_date
```

(Again, for a very large table, we probably want to break that transaction up into smaller chunks, by including a predicate on gvkey in the inline view, to limit the number of rows returned/updated.)

Doing this in batches of `gvkey` ranges is a reasonable approach... eg.

```
/* first batch */    WHERE r.gvkey >=    1 AND r.gvkey <  100
/* second run  */    WHERE r.gvkey >=  100 AND r.gvkey <  200
/* third batch */    WHERE r.gvkey >=  200 AND r.gvkey <  300
```

---

Obviously, there are other approaches/SQL patterns to accomplish an equivalent result. I've had success with this approach.

To emphasize an earlier **IMPORTANT** note: this relies on behavior that is *not guaranteed*, and which the MySQL Reference Manual warns against (using user-defined variables like this.)

Comment: Thanks  @spencer7593, it worked really well. It took me a while to get it but the explanations was great too! To get the next date, I would only ned to order by descending order right ?
Also, my table is not too large so performance was not an issue at all. It took me less than a minute.

Comment: Yes, you could do the same thing to get the following date, just reverse the ordering.  To make sure you can make effective use of an available index, do the the whole thing in descending order... **`ORDER BY gvkey DESC, data_date DESC`**.  And using this same pattern you could grab *any* columns from the "previous" row, if you wanted to store the price from the previous row. (And obviously, the `prev_date` column isn't automatically maintained, when you later insert or delete rows.)